# Networking question ip routing

Tags: networking, ip, routing, gateway

Let me start by saying I am a complete novice with very little networking knowledge.

I have set up a VPN via a guide and everything is working fine, however, I would like for the IP routing or gateway to stay permanently as my current solution is only temporary.

Basically I used the command

```
ip route | grep default
```

and it shows

```
default via 206.189.112.1 dev eth0 onlink
```

The guide I am using requires it to be

```
default via 206.189.112.1 dev eth0 proto static
```

Which I managed a workaround by using replacing the above with

```
sudo ip route add default via 206.189.112.1 dev eth0 **proto static**
```

I was wondering how I could change it from "onlink" to "proto static" permanently.

Thanks

Comment: Rather than asking about changing magic words, read `man ip-route`, and understand what the routing options mean.